# Ruby test data generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I want to populate some data to use in my Rails app. However I cannot decide which of data generator is the best for me.

I want to fast and clean generator. It should create plenty of data as well.

I have 3 of them, random_data, forger and faker.

Which one is the best? Can you share you experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My choice is [ffaker](https://github.com/EmmanuelOga/ffaker#readme). It's quite fast and maintained by Emmanuel.

Comment: I checked https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/random_data_generation out after created the question. And result, I believe that I should use Faker. However I am not user how fast it is.